# How do I edit a .py config file in a subdirectory?

Tags: python, file, config

I'm trying to read and edit a config file in python. Here is the file structure:

```
main.py
folder
-> __init__.py
-> module.py
-> config.py
```

I have four files:

**main.py**

```
import folder.config as config
import folder.module as module

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config.x = 2
    module.foo()
```

****init**.py**

```
import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

**module.py**

```
import config

def foo():
    print("Result from function: " + str(config.x))
```

**config.py**

```
x = 10
```

I expect the result from calling 'foo' to be '2', but instead it prints '10', the config file's default value. How can I ensure that changes made to 'config.py' in 'main.py' persist to other modules?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use JSON or csv or any other format to store values?

EDIT:
I suggest following solution:

#### main.py

```
import folder.config as config
import folder.module as module

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config.set_x(2)
    module.foo()
```

#### init.py

```
import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

#### module.py

```
import config

def foo(): print(f"Result from function: { str(config.get_x()) }")
```

#### config.py

```
import json

def read_json():
    with open("data.json") as f: d = json.load(f)
    return d

def write_json(d):
    with open('data.json', 'w') as f: json.dump(d, f)

try:
    data = read_json()
except:
    data = {}
    write_json({})

def set_x(val):
    data["x"] = val
    write_json(data)

def get_x():
    print(data)
    return data["x"]
```

Comment: The Problem with your solution is that you Import and change the imported value but don't update the file. If you print config.x in main.py it should be changed. Maybe try out to change module.config.x in main and print that out. But I think that's not really that what you want you probably want to update the file

Comment: Thank you for responding! How would I go about updating the config.py file?

Comment: I really don't recommend it. This will be a pretty hard job. Better use formats which exists for storing data. What exactly is your goal for config.py? what do you want to store there

Comment: You will have massive performance issues with larger files because you would have to read the file into a string search the string for your variable name and read the rest of the line till EOL. Or you just import JSON and use 2 functions. write and read. They are well documentated you will find many tutorials on how to work with JSON

Comment: My goal for config.py is to save a class instance to be loaded from other modules. If JSON has this capability, then I’d happily switch to it, but I couldn’t find how to do it either.

Comment: You don't need a class instance for storing data. You can just read the JSON file in config.py and create there functions to change the data

Comment: Thank you! I switched to using JSON, and it works.

Comment: great nice to hear that